# Is it Required to Verify receiver numbers on twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am using [Twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api) to send SMS to users .

My question is here that is it required to verify every reciver numver on twilio?

right now its saying for every receiver.

> "The number  is unverified. Trial accounts cannot send
>   messages to unverified numbers; verify  at
>   twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified, or purchase a Twilio
>   number to send messages to unverified numbers."

Thanks
Dalvir

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It is only required to verify numbers that you want to send SMS to when your account is in trial mode. If you upgrade your account you will be able to send SMS messages to any number.

Comment: Great! Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: yes I have and posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474599/send-formated-messages-through-twilio

Comment: Hi @philnash , my client says that he has already added credits to his account, but his account still says 'Trial Account'. What seems to the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know there. It would be best if you contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and include the Account SID that is having the problem and they will be able to help you out @ShishirShetty.

Comment: @philnash , is it possible to verify outgoing number via API using free trial account. I used the code given in sample. but it returned null.
Will it also require sms verification of that number?

Comment: @mck Which sample do you mean?

Comment: I am using below code with mine free trial account and i am getting null in return


string AccountSid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
string AuthToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var twilios = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
var callerId = twilios.AddOutgoingCallerId("+923157157157", "John", null, null);

Comment: Which language is that? Sorry, trying to look through the documentation to find out what's going on.

Comment: That's not supposed to be a string returned from that call, but a `ValidationRequestResult` which has a `ValidationCode` attribute. `null` doesn't seem like the right result at all. @mck can you start a new question, share a bit more of the code that you're using and we can try to solve it there as the comments here aren't the best place for it.

Comment: Yes it is returning ValidationRequestRe‌​sult. But all the values of its attributes are null.
AccountSid is null.
ValidationCode is null.
Code is simple as given on twilio documentation. I verified a number from twilio website and send sms to that number.
It sent successfully. Now i want to add verified outbound caller ID with the API.

Comment: @philnash is there any free API which can send sms to any number free of cost?

Comment: @HamzaZafeer sending SMS messages costs I'm afraid, especially if you want them to be reliable. I don't know of a free service that I can recommend.

Comment: i have upgrade the twilio but still I can not send message on unverified number

Comment: If you can’t send messages, you should get an error back in the API response that describes what is wrong now. Read that error message and it will help.